# If we know that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges, can we conclude that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{a_n}$ diverges?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Suppose that we have $a_n > 0$.  Then if we know that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges, can we conclude that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{a_n}$ diverges?

On the contrary, if we know that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ diverges, can we conclude that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{a_n}$ converges?

Comment: Any thoughts?  What do the standard examples tell you?

Comment: yes,it is just a sub n

Comment: Do you mean series, or sequence?

Comment: it is series not sequence

Comment: Heck... $1/a_n$ might not even be defined... what is preventing some values of $a_n$ from being identically zero?

Comment: the question says that each a sub n is not equal to zero

Answer (score 3):

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\text{ converges}\implies \lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$$
$$\implies\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{a_n}\ne0\implies \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{a_n}\text{ diverges}$$